# Vertical align text inside inline li

Tags: css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I am trying to create a self-adjusting horizontal menu and looking to vertically align text within `li`'s that are displayed as `inline`. Currently the text is glued to the top. All my attempts have failed. See markup below.

```css
#nav 
    {
        display: inline-table;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 10em;
        margin-bottom: 10em;
    }

    #nav > li
    {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        height: 8em;
        width: 8em;
        padding: 0px 5px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: #0a547c;
    }

    #nav > li:hover
    {
        background-color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; height: 30em;">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li onclick="window.open('myLink1', '_self');">Text A</li>
        <li onclick="window.open('myLink2', '_self');">Text B</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I don't want to use `line-height` because the text may wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using `float`, I think you should change `display:inline:` to `display:flex:` and use `align-items:center;` to bring them vertically in the middle. Them wrap the text around with a `span` so that you can control the text styles more easily.

```css
#nav 
    {
        display: inline-table;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-bottom: 10em;
    }

    #nav > li
    {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        float: left;
        height: 8em;
        width: 8em;
        padding: 0px 5px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: #0a547c;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #nav>li>span{
      vertical-align:middle;
      display:block;
      width:100%;
    }

    #nav > li:hover
    {
        background-color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; height: 30em;">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li onclick="window.open('myLink1', '_self');"><span>Text A</span></li>
        <li onclick="window.open('myLink2', '_self');"><span>Text B</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` should help you in this case, while float is breaking this behavior.

```css
    #nav 
    {
        display: table;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 10em;
        margin-bottom: 10em;
    }

    #nav > li
    {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 8em;
        width: 8em;
        padding: 0px 5px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: #0a547c;
    }

    #nav > li:hover
    {
        background-color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; height: 30em;">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li onclick="window.open('myLink1', '_self');">Text A</li>
        <li onclick="window.open('myLink2', '_self');">Text B</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```